# overridePendingTransition shows enter animation only

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-animation

When the user changes the language locale, I would like to reload the activity with the new locale. I want to create an animated transition when finishing the Activity and starting it again.

The transition animation is as follows:

The exit animation is to scale the activity to the center of the screen.
The enter animation is to scale the activity from the center of the screen.

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.scale_to_center);
Intent intent =new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.scale_from_center, 0);
```

and my `scale_to_center.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="0"
        android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0" 
        android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

and my `scale_from_center.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:fromYScale="0" android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:fromXScale="0" android:toXScale="1.0" 
        android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

The problem is that ONLY the enter transition appears and the exit transition do not appear. I tried to add a delay to the exit transition but it didn't work either.

However when I changed the code to only animate the exit of application. It worked.

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.scale_to_center);
```

Thanks.

Comment: `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>`solve my problem, maybe you can try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the two animations on the method `overridePendingTransition` and call finish **after** you've called `startActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.scale_from_center, R.anim.scale_to_center);
finish();
```

Comment: @Luksporg I tried this before, it works perfectly on target 2.X. However, I can't see it working on a 4.0 emulator. Any reason why?

Comment: @M.ES It's not working at all or it's incomplete again? I've just tested my code and the animation appears to work(the enter animation at least works) but the old activity leaves some frames when animating, but I think that is happening because of my weak computer not being able to make the emulator display the animation fast enough.

Comment: @Laksporg On 4.0 emulator both the enter and exit animations appears overlapping. On 2.X works perfectly. DO you think that's overlap will not appear on a real 4.X device?

Comment: @M.ES I don't know if that happens because of ICS or because of the emulator. I don't have a real device with ICS to use it for tests.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work here as well. I fixed it creating a null_animation.xml:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
android:fromYDelta="0%p"
android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```