# Activity transition obscured when new activity is fixed in position

Tags: android, android-activity, transition

When a button is pressed in my Activity, I want to finish the current Activity and start a new one. I want the new activity to be fixed in position, and revealed behind the outgoing activity as the old one slides off the screen.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OverviewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.hold, R.anim.slide_out_top);
```

So for the new activity I'm applying a `hold` animation; this is a placeholder which doesn't animate anything. I have also tried passing `0`instead of `R.anim.hold` but that doesn't work either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromXDelta="0"
  android:toXDelta="0"
  android:duration="@integer/slide_anim_duration" />
```

The new activity is being displayed immediately in its fixed location on top of the outgoing activity, so the sliding animation of the old activity is being obscured.

Is there any way I can make the new activity be drawn behind the old one, while the old one is animating off the screen?

Comment: are you calling the intent in a thread or something.

Comment: @GeorgeThomas No, this is on the main thread in response to a button click.

Comment: @pskink Makes no difference.

Comment: I have figured out what the problem is. The new activity is being displayed immediately in its fixed location *on top* of the outgoing activity. So the sliding animation of the old activity is being obscured.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. After I understood exactly what the problem was, I found an existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reordering the statements may work for you

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, OverviewActivity.class);
      overridePendingTransition(R.anim.hold, R.anim.slide_out_top);   
      startActivity(intent);
      finish();
```

You are overriding the transition when you have started your new  activity and called `finish()` on the last one.

Comment: No, that doesn't help. The documentation states that `overridePendingTransition()` should be called _after_ `finish()` or `startActivity()` anyway.

Comment: Swapping the order of `finish()` and `startActivity()` doesn't help either.

Comment: Try this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284238/overridependingtransition-shows-enter-animation-only

Comment: Thanks, but that's a subtly different issue and the accepted answer there doesn't solve this problem.